# How to execute long task on Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm getting a problem on Telegram when some step from my Dialog needs more than 15 seconds to perform. The error description is: POST to name_of_bot timed out after 15s.

I've found an option to do that using proactive messages feature from the framework, but I would not like to create a whole architecture based on proactive messages. It seems wrong.

So, what is the best practices to perform long tasks on Microsoft Bot Framework, without timeout?

Comment: It seems we've found a solution. We've removed the async from controller action which is the endpoint of the bot. The timeout has stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, due to the Bot Framework's current architecture, you need to use a proactive message if the process to respond to the incoming activity is going to take longer than 15 seconds.

**Bot Framework SDK v4 (Node)**

```
this.onMessage(async context => {
  const conversationReference = TurnContext.getConversationReference(context.activity);
  context.adapter.continueConversation(conversationReference, async turnContext => {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 20000));
    await turnContext.sendActivity('Hello, World!');
  });
});
```